# Understanding pre/post in pseudo-code notation

Tags: pseudocode

I am following these [examples of C# code](http://www.cs.pomona.edu/~kim/cs136/s98/Lectures/Lec9.html). But I am little confused by the Pseudo Code comments all over the place.

For example:

```
public void addToHead(Object value)
// pre: value non-null
// post: adds element to head of list
{
    SinglyLinkedListElement temp =
        new SinglyLinkedListElement(value);
    if (tail == null) {
        tail = temp;
        tail.setNext(tail);
    }
    else {
        temp.setNext(tail.next());
        tail.setNext(temp);
    }
    count++;
}
```

What does `Pre` and `Post` mean here?

I've never seen `Post` used here. I know what `Post` means in the context of the Web and HTML etc, but not in pure code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Pre" indicates an assumption made at the beginning of execution. In this case, it's indicating that the value passed in is assumed to be not null.

"Post" indicates an assumption made at the end of the execution, i.e. what the routine actually does. In this case, when the routine finishes a new element will have been added to the end of the list. If the routine modifies its parameters or has any other side effects, those modifications should be listed in the "Post" as well.

Comment: Thanks Graeme. With regards to the "Pre", it is a hint to also ensure (and not assume) that the value passed is NOT NULL correct? Via a NULL check for example

Comment: It's just saying that the code in the routine assumes that value is not NULL, i.e. that the code does not check.